# Navier-Stokes with non-newtonian fluids

Tags: fluid-mechanics, chemical-engineering

So I've got a problem here in fluids. It's driving me insane but I know I'm missing something simple.

Up until now we've worked with Newtonian fluids resulting in the "normal" NS equations in Cartesian coordinates (ie [1](http://www.personal.psu.edu/users/w/z/wzl113/Teaching/HW15.gif)). those apply only to non-compressible, Newtonian fluids. We were specifically given the general tensor version of the equations( i.e. [image: 2]), and some data about the shear stress vs the shear rate, and told it was a power law fluid in this question (so non-Newtonian).

I understand from the derivations for how we get from the "general" NS equation (the screenshot) to the "normal" equation I showed first above, but I cannot figure out how to apply the general form to this power law fluid (which behaves as a pseudoplastic given we have a n < 1). I've searched literature and our textbooks and no one goes through the derivation. Any help?